# How do I make an If Not statement with multiple 'or' s?

Tags: vba

I am trying to make a command-prompt like program, and I want an unknown command statement when the user does not type a correct command.

```
If Not TextBox3.Text = "help" Or "commands" Or "run" Then
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & "Unknown command. Type 'help' for help.")
End If
```

The error is [indicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHGkl.png) as being on the first line.

Comment: Please post your code and error message as text in your post, both for the convenience of answerers and so Google can direct future searchers to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make it

```
TextBox3.Text = "help" or TextBox3.Text = "commamds" or TextBox3.Text= "run" then
```